# What does the `Stack=1, Locals=1, Args_size=1` Mean in Java Bytecode?

Tags: java, bytecode

I made a simple class to learn how to read Java byte code. What does the line

```
Stack=1, Locals=1, Args_size=1
```

mean in the folloiwng code?

```
public Demo();
  Code:
   Stack=1, Locals=1, Args_size=1
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return
  LineNumberTable: 
   line 1: 0
```

Answer (score 6):

It means you have one argument (the object to be initialised), one local variable (the object to be initialised) and at most one object on the stack (the object to be intialised)

Comment: So is Args_size the number of items placed on the stack at the beginning of the method call?

Comment: yes. The `this` is notionally on the stack when the constructor is called.