# What does stack=1 (or any integer value) mean in Java bytecode

Tags: java, java-8, jvm, bytecode, javap

I've been trying to understand how the bytecode of the following Java code works. I couldn't find the explanation of what the stack=1 and the stack=4 part mean.

Java Code:

```
public class SimpleRecursion {

    public int factorial(int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return n*factorial(n - 1);
    }

}
```

I compiled the SimpleRecursion.java class and this is what I get after executing javap on SimpleRecursion.class:

Default constructor bytecode: (stack=1 is present in 5th line)

> ```
> public SimpleRecursion();
> descriptor: ()V
> flags: ACC_PUBLIC
> Code:
>   stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
>      0: aload_0
>      1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
>      4: return
>   LineNumberTable:
>     line 1: 0
> ```

Bytecode of the factorial method: (stack=4 is present in 5th line)

> ```
> public int factorial(int);
> descriptor: (I)I
> flags: ACC_PUBLIC
> Code:
>   stack=4, locals=2, args_size=2
>      0: iload_1
>      1: ifne          6
>      4: iconst_1
>      5: ireturn
>      6: iload_1
>      7: aload_0
>      8: iload_1
>      9: iconst_1
>     10: isub
>     11: invokevirtual #2                  // Method factorial:(I)I
>     14: imul
>     15: ireturn
>   LineNumberTable:
>     line 4: 0
>     line 5: 4
>     line 7: 6
>   StackMapTable: number_of_entries = 1
>     frame_type = 6 /* same */
> ```

What's the meaning of the stack=1 and stack=4?

Update:
It appears that there is a similar question :

[What does the `Stack=1, Locals=1, Args_size=1` Mean in Java Bytecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241914/what-does-the-stack-1-locals-1-args-size-1-mean-in-java-bytecode)

But it doesn't answer the following questions:

How does the compiler know that there will be at most 4 objects on the stack for the factorial method? Does it count the number of iload/aload instructions?

Comment: The question is still a dup ... despite your adding new subquestions after it was marked as dup.  If you want answers, ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks @StephenC I will ask a new question